Magic T gates need Real-time Error Correction integrated to the QPU Stack or only Pauli-frame Update?
I am aware of the initial paper by Barbara Terhal- Quantum Error Correction for Quantum Memories, where it is stated that

Let $r_{proc}$ be the rate (in bauds) at which syndrome bits are processed and $r_{gen}$ be the rate at which these syndrome bits are generated. We can argue that if $r_{gen}/r_{proc} = f > 1$, a small initial backlog in processing syndrome
data will lead to an exponential slow down during the computation, . . .

However, she also says that

In conclusion, one can argue that one does not need to physically implement any logical or elementary Pauli operation, but one does need to know the logical Pauli before one can proceed further with the computation

So, I am confused if one needs to have a decoder integrated in a QPU computing the error (Pauli frame) and being used as the input of the conditional physical SX gate or if one can apply the conditional SX gate in software (fast enough) via Pauli frame update (since SX gate is a Clifford gate) as it seems to be stated in the paper arXiv:2409.07707 pp. 5

Here, $\pi/2$-rotation gates, which are simply Pauli gates with a global phase change, are shown as gray boxes to emphasize that they do not need to be applied explicitly but only change the Pauli frame

